# How to send text to favorite editor without switching windows

Tags: microsoft-word, browser, automation, copy-paste

I want to send selected in web page contents (text + images) to Word or Libre Writer via right button of shortcut right from browser without switching windows.

I searched through several automation tools, but they all require switching windows.

Is it possible to do so WITHOUT switching windows back and fourth again with some utility?

I guess it should work similar to on-line tools to save snippets to cloud, but to editor window.

Comment: How should it decide destination if multiple documents in such editor are open?

Comment: I use `FastStone Capture` to capture image and sent it directly to `MS Word` without switching. But, it would capture area I select as image only. Another tool I use is inbuilt windows "Step Recorder".

Comment: Take a look at clipboard manager tools. With those you can just copy stuff from any application without switching and later paste it from the clipboard history to your text editor.

Comment: @Juhász I believe there should be an option to select default editor window to send text, images, etc. As well as may be other options, like add line feed, align, etc.

Comment: @Kapep Yes, a clipboard manager could be an option, but if you copy many times, you will probably have to paste it many times again as you finish copying. I guess a tool to do it just once, with no fuss. I added it to my question.

Comment: @Sandeep Yes, a screenshoter does a part of a job, as well as clipboard managers. But i believe a tool exist universal and less effort, just added to my answer.